# Keep the form open when sending data to the table

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have this code with multiple forms within the same page:

- test1 page:

```html
<select id="mudar_produto"> 
    <option value="#produto_1">Novo Produto Higiene</option> 
    <option value="#produto_2">Entrada de Produtos Higiene</option> 
    <option value="#produto_3">Novo Produto Nutricia</option> 
</select>
```

```
<section class="hide-section" id="produto_1">
    <form id="form3" action="./teste2" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()"> 
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoProd" name="DescricaoProd" required="" style="width:350px">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoUnid" name="DescricaoUnid" style="width:160px" required="" size="120">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="botao submit">Registo</button>
    </form> 
</section>

<section class="hide-section" id="produto_2"> 
    <form name="form4" action="./teste2" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()"> 
         <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Entrada de Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br>       
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Data Entrada">Data Entrada</label></strong>
            <input id="DataEntrada" type="date" name="DataEntrada" required="" style="width:180px" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Produto">Produto</label></strong>
        <select id="first_dd" name="Produto" style="width:250px" required> 
            <option></option> 
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.ProdHigieneteste WHERE Ativo = 1 ORDER BY DescricaoProd ASC"; 
                $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){ 
                    echo '<option value="'.$ln['IDProd'].'"> '.$ln['DescricaoProd'].'</option>'; 
                    $valencia[$ln['IDProd']]=array('DescricaoUnid'=>$ln['DescricaoUnid'],'DescricaoUnid'=>$ln['DescricaoUnid']); 
                } 
            ?> 
        </select> 
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong>
        <select id="second_dd" name="Unid" style="width:150px" required> 
            <option></option> 
            <?php
                foreach ($valencia as $key => $value) { 
                    echo '<option data-id="'.$key.'" value="'.$value['DescricaoUnid'].'">'.$value['DescricaoUnid'].'</option>'; 
                }
            ?> 
        </select><br> 
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Quantidade">Quantidade</label></strong>
            <input type="text" id="Quantidade" name="Quantidade" style="width:80px" required="" size="40">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Preço">Preço</label></strong>
            <input type="text" id="Preco" name="Preco" style="width:100px" value="0.00">
        </div> 
    </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" name="submit1" class="botao submit">Registo</button>
    </form>
</section>   

<section class="hide-section" id="produto_3"> 
    <form id="form3" name="form3" action="./teste2" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()" > 
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Nutricia</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong>
                <input type="text" id="ProdNutricia" name="ProdNutricia" style="width:350px" required="" size="120" />
            </div> 
    </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" name="submit2" class="botao submit">Registo</button>
    </form> 
</section>
```

In the page **teste2** I make the insertion of the data in the table of the database:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.location = "teste1";
</script>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $name = $_POST['DescricaoProd'];
  $unid = $_POST['DescricaoUnid'];    

$sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

header("Location: teste1");

$conn->close();
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

  $data = $_POST['DataEntrada'];
  $produto = $_POST['Produto'];  
  $unidade = $_POST['Unid'];   
  $quantidade = $_POST['Quantidade'];
  $preco = $_POST['Preco']; 


$sql = "INSERT INTO regEntradahigieneteste (DataEntrada,Produto,Unid,Quantidade,Preco) 
VALUES ('$data','$produto','$unidade','$quantidade','$preco')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

$sql1 = "UPDATE StockHigieneteste SET Quantidade = Quantidade +" . $quantidade . " WHERE StockHigieneteste.IDProd =" . $produto;

 if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

header("Location: teste1");

$conn->close(); 
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){

    $name = $_POST['ProdNutricia'];  

$sql = "INSERT INTO ProdNutriciateste (ProdNutricia) 
VALUES ('$name')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockNutriciateste (ProdNutricia) 
VALUES ('$name')";

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

header("Location: teste1");

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Everything is working correctly with the insertion of data in the table, but when I do the insertion and does the header ("Location: teste1"); closes the form I was filling out and I want to keep it open, since I may have to insert several types of products on the same form.

Comment: If you want to submit without redrawing the page, you'll have to use AJAX.  A library such as JQuery makes this much easier.  The redirect on page teste2 will never fire, because you already have output (`<script language=...`).  A good habit to get in to is to never print anything until you've done all the PHP work you need to do.

Comment: @Tim Morton, Can you give me an example so I understand how?

Comment: I would assume that `header("Location: test1")` is just reopening the page as if it were a new call. Unsure but just try to `return "completed"` instead and see if that does anything? 

If you take some time to read over tutorials on jQuery AJAX and this site [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp) provides some simple examples. Right now I'm don't see any ajax in your code. You should play around with this more to get a better feel for it.

Comment: @Iniciante - I can, but remember SO is not intended to be a tutorial site (even though I believe a good answers are always didactic).  It will take me a few days to get to it, though.  I'll try to work you through a single form and you can run with it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Some explanation to start with:

1. I have cleaned up your HTML markup. You may have gotten the look you desired, but the markup is badly broken.  A good editor will help you with making a [well-formed](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3768916) document that [validates](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html%20validates).
2. I've used [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/) for styling. [Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/) is another good choice.
3. [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) is used as the basis for Javascript event monitoring and AJAX
4. This is not copy and paste code.  It's untested; it's purpose is to point you in the right direction.
5. The code is commented to help you understand what it's doing.

Since this is how SO is showing the code, we start off with the javascript and the HTML:

```js
// this delays execution until after the page has loaded
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  // this monitors the button, id=submit-form-1, for a click event
  // and then runs the function, submitForm1()
  $('#submit-form-1').on('click', function() {
    submitForm('#form1');
  });
  
  // could be repeated for another form...
  $('#submit-form-2').on('click', function() {
    submitForm('#form2');
  });
  
  
});

// this function does an AJAX call to "insert.php".
// it expects a reply in JSON.
function submitForm(whichForm) {
  var datastring = $(whichForm).serialize();

  // see what you're sending:
  alert('You would be sending: ' + datastring);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    data: datastring,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.status=='success') {
          alert('successfully uploaded');
        } else {
          alert('failed to insert');
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("This example can't actually connect to the PHP script, so this error appears.");
    }
});
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="produto_1">
  <!-- 
    note that the form is identified with id="form1".  
    "id" has to be unique. Nothing else can have id="form1".
    There are no action nor method attributes, 
    since AJAX is submitting the form contents.
  -->
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="form1">
    <!-- 
      field named "action" will be used in PHP script 
    -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert_form_1" />
    <!-- use CSS for styling, not <center>, <strong>, etc. -->
    <h1 class="text-center">Produtos de Higiene</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="DescricaoProd" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome do Produto</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DescricaoProd" name="DescricaoProd" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="DescricaoUnid" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Unidade</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DescricaoUnid" name="DescricaoUnid" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <!-- 
          button type is button, not submit.
          Otherwise the form will try to submit.
          We want the javascript to submit, not the form.
        -->
        <button type="button" id="submit-form-1" class="btn btn-success">Registo</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form> 
</section>

<!-- set up another form in the same way... -->
<form id="form2">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert_form_2" />
...
<button type="button" id="submit-form-2">submit form 2</button>
</form>
```

The above markup and javascript should make an AJAX `POST` request to `insert.php`, and listen for a reply.

#### insert.php

```
<?php

/**
  * note:  It is a good practice to NEVER have anything before the <?php tag.
  * 
  * Always try to separate logic from presentation.  This is why you should 
  * start with PHP on the top, and never do any output until you are done
  * with processing.  Better yet, have separate files for logic and presentation
  *
  */ 

// if $_POST doesn't have ['action'] key, stop the script. Every request will have
// an action.
if(!array_key_exists('action', $_POST)) {
  die("Sorry, I don't know what I'm supposed to do.");
}


// database initialization could (should) go on another page so it can be reused!
// set up PDO connection
// this section credit to https://phpdelusions.net/pdo
// use your credentials here...
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'your_db_name';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";

// helpful initializations, such as default fetch is associative array
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

// instantiate database
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

// end database initialization


// whenever you have to do something over again, break it out into a function
// this function prevents warnings if the variable is not present in $_POST
function get_post($var_name) {
  $out = '';
  if(array_key_exists($var_name,$_POST)) {
    $out = $_POST[$var_name];
  }
  return $out;
}



// assign variables
$action = get_post('action');
$name = get_post('DescricaoProd');
$unid = get_post('DescricaoUnid');    


// All output of this script is JSON, so set the header to make it so.  
// There can be NO output before this!
// Not even a blank line before the <?php start tag.
header('Content-Type: application/json');


// take action based on value of "action".  

if($action=='insert_form_1') {

    $error = false;
    $output = array('message' => 'success');

    // Use placeholders, never (NEVER NEVER NEVER) php variables!
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) VALUES (?,?)";
    $pdo->prepare($query);
    $result = $pdo->execute([$name, $unid]); // don't miss the [] which is a shortcut for array()
    if(!$result) { $error = true; }

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) VALUES (?,?)";
    $pdo->prepare($query);
    $result = $pdo->execute([$name, $unid]); // don't miss the [] which is a shortcut for array()
    if(!$result) { $error = true; }

    // note, I just repeated myself, so this probably should be refactored...

    // send a message back to the calling AJAX:
    if($error) {
        $output = array('status' => 'failed');
    } else {
        $output = array('status' => 'success');
    }

    print json_encode($output);
    die; // nothing more to do

}

// you could have additional actions to perform in the same script.
// or, you could use different files...

if($action=='insert_form_2') {
    // do insert for form 2
}

// etc.
```

Comment: In the chrome console gives "Error 500 - Internal Server Error", it should have some problem in the part of the code

Comment: 500 errors are usually a problem with the server set up.  I presume the PDO connection is something you haven't used before?  Make sure your php.ini has it enabled. You can verify where the server gets all tangled up by using `die('good to here');` starting at the top of the script and keep moving it until the script croaks.  Most likely PDO is not configured. The code should be good, but it is untested...

Comment: oh, I just realized you said "In the chrome console..."  Sounds like the AJAX worked for you :)

Comment: In that sense you are right, I still work with mysqli, but in the future I will go all out to pdo. I'll try the solution you gave me.

Comment: Yes ajax works, it is only giving some error in the part of the php code that I have not been able to solve nor to realize where it will be

Comment: mysqli is fine, as long as you use prepared statements.  I don't work with mysql anymore, and I've found mysqli to be really...  *ugly*. PDO is a lot closer to what I work with.  Keep in mind that mysqli does prepared statements differently. You'll have to research how it does it; it's a little weird and the documentation stinks.